# How can I add a false line to a script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, permissions, shebang

I need to write a script that is exactly 2 lines long but I must end my file with a new line. If I add a new line to the script, it will turn to 3, yet I need 2 lines.
How do I go about it?

I have tried:

```
           sed -i -z 's/$/\n/g' file.txt
```

Also tried:

```
           echo $">> <file_name>
```

Comment: I don't understand, what a _false line_ is. Maybe you could post the file as it looks before adding that mysterious line, and how it should look afterwards. You can represent newline characters by something like `<LF>`, to communicate where exactly you want to have newlines and where you don't.

Comment: Your question is not very precise. Please rephrase it. I mean: if your script has to be two lines and must end with a newline, it will ALWAYS have three lines. There are no tricks to avoid this! You have to drop one of those requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably misunderstand your homework. in linux text files each line is terminated with **"newline"**  by definition, and file always end with newline. this is done automatically from text editor, there is nothing extra intended from your side.

you can double check from hex editor where 0x0a represents \n "newline" character

```
hexdump -C file.txt
```

consider different platforms have different line endings

```
\n   unix
\r   darwin
\r\n windows
```

edit:

shell scripts containing only two lines are very unlikely. because first line is always shebang, there is only one line remaining for commands. If you are forced to write such script it looks ugly

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World"; echo "my first shell script";
```

Comment: Exactly. You're right. The editor adds a new line automatically. I got confused with the line part. I have solved it. Thanks a lot